# emit qml signal on start application

Tags: qt, qml, signals-slots

Is there a way to emit or is there a signal that is emitted at the start of an application in qml?

My purpose is to check wether some values are in a list and when, then I want to enable a button.

Something like:

```
Rectangle{ id:main 
   Button {
      id:myButton
      checkable: false
      onClicked: { /* do something */ }
   }
   // First variant
   Connections: {
      target: myClass
      onSignalEmit() { myButton.checkable = true }
   }
   // Second varinat
   emit startUp()
}
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but `Component.onCompleted:` may do what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Retired Ninja said you can use Component.onCompleted in this case

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-expressions.html#javascript-in-application-startup-code

```
Rectangle{ 
    id:main
    ....
    Component.onCompleted: startUp();
}
```